# Identify Code Origin from EF-Generated SQL?

Tags: entity-framework, query-optimization

What is the best way to identify the source of a (very) inefficient Entity Framework query when I only have the captured SQL available?

Comment: Is this the very first query in your application? Have you tried to run generated sql against db? Did you consider impact of views generation?

Comment: The application generates many queries from many different persistence services in the code - I am wondering if there is a heuristic or helpful approach to take a generated SQL statement and efficiently find the code that generated it.  (I can't just look at what tables it's querying because it doesn't narrow it down enough - there might be a whole range of operations that queries against that table.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using some kind of logging framework, you could do something like this in your DbContext constructor:

```
this.Database.Log = sql =>
{
    if (sql.Contains(/* part of the offending query */))
    {
        Logger.Log($"Found it! {Environment.StackTrace}")
    }
}
```